Let $\dim(V) < \infty $ and suppose that $\tau \in \mathcal L (V)$ satisfies $\tau^2 = O $. Show that $2 rk(\tau ) \le dim (V) $
Let $\dim(V) < \infty $ and suppose that $\tau \in \mathcal L (V) $ satisfies $\tau^2 = \mathcal O $ (Where $\mathcal O$ is the zero map):

show that $2 rk(\tau ) \le \dim (V) $.

I proved that but without using the condition "$\dim(V) < \infty $".
I proved it as the follow:
By Rank Plus Nullity Theorem :
$$ \dim(V) = rk (\tau) + \operatorname{null}(\tau) $$
$ \operatorname{im}(\tau ) \subset \ker (\tau ) $. Indeed, if we take a $$w \in \operatorname{im}( \tau) \Rightarrow \exists v \in V : \tau (v)=w \Rightarrow 0 = \tau^2 (v) = \tau (w) \Rightarrow w \in \ker(\tau) $$
So $rk (\tau) \le \operatorname{null} (\tau) $ Then
$$ \dim(V) \ge rk (\tau) + rk (\tau) =2 rk(\tau) $$
So I see like this is true for the vector spaces that have infinte dimension too. Is that true ?
This is the proof of The  Rank Plus Nullity Theorem in the book which I study; " Advanced linear algebra by steven Roman":
The Rank Plus Nullity Theorem
Let $\tau\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Since any subspace of$V$ has a complement, we can write
$$V=\ker(\tau)\oplus\ker(\tau)^c$$
where ker$(\tau)^c$ is a complement of ker$(\tau)$ in $V.$ It follows that
$$\dim(V)=\dim(\ker(\tau))+\dim(\ker(\tau)^c)$$
Now, the restriction of $\tau$ to ker$(\tau)^c$
$$\tau^c{:}\ker(\tau)^c\to W$$
is injective, since
$$\ker(\tau^c)=\ker(\tau)\cap\ker(\tau)^c=\{0\}$$
Also, $\operatorname{im}(\tau^{c})\subseteq\operatorname{im}(\tau).$ For the reverse inclusion, if $\tau(v)\in\operatorname{im}(\tau)$ then since
$v=u+w$ for $u\in \ker(\tau)$ and $w\in \ker(\tau)^c$,we have
$$\tau(v)=\tau(u)+\tau(w)=\tau(w)=\tau^c(w)\in\mathrm{im}(\tau^c)$$
Thus $\operatorname{im}(\tau^c)=\operatorname{im}(\tau).$ It follows that
$$\ker(\tau)^c\approx\mathrm{im}(\tau)$$
From this, we deduce the following theorem.
$\textbf{Theorem 2. 8 Let }\tau \in \mathcal{L} ( V, W).$

Any complement of $\ker(\tau)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{im}(\tau )$

$( \textbf{The rank plus nullity theorem})$


$$\dim(\ker(\tau))+\dim(\operatorname{im}(\tau))=\dim(V)$$
or, in other notation,
$$\mathrm{rk}(\tau)+\mathrm{null}(\tau)=\dim(V)$$

For context, see also this question.

You used the assumption implicitly by citing the rank-nullity theorem, which requires the domain of the linear transformation in question to be finite-dimensional.

@infinitylord in my book there is no a condition like that. Also I read the proof of this theorem and I can't see that he uses this condition in his proof. I added the proof to my OP. Can you look at it ?

@DietrichBurde Sorry, But I can't see your point.

The inequality is trivial for $\dim V = +\infty$, because every extended real is $\leq +\infty$...

@BrunoB but the dimension is the cardinality of the basis. so they maybe be aleph zero ır continum as an example. Also I thought that I already have proved it for any vector space. My question is why is there this condition in the question?
